# Forward declaration and inheritance

Tags: c++

The following code generates an error in the `getFoo` function because `MockFoo` hasn't yet been defined as being inherited from `IFoo`. How can I fix this? The simplest way is to change `_foo`'s type to IFooPtr. But I'd prefer not to make this change if possible. I can't change the order the classes are defined in.

```
class MockFoo;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MockFoo> MockFooPtr;

class MockBar: public IBar
{
    virtual IStructPtr getFoo() const {
        return _foo;
    }
    ...

    MockFooPtr _foo;
};

class MockFoo: public IFoo
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: can you move the definition of the `getFoo` function after the definition of the `MockFoo` class ? (or better yet into a different .cpp source file)

Comment: I presume that once you fill in the details, it is not possible to simple fully declare `MockFoo` before `MockBar` like it would be possible in this example, correct?

Comment: @Euro Micelli Correct!

Comment: is it just me or does it really get to anyone else when people use foo and bar in their examples its makes it so illogical to follow, mockfoo, mockbar, ifoo, ibar all mashed together ... just use easy to follow names, never mind that your defining your accessor function in the class declaration

Comment: @AngryDuck What names would you suggest then for the example above?

Comment: i dont know but how about just using a different name for your, class, inherited class, pointer, function name and member variable perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd declare the typedef as:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<IFoo> IFooPtr;
```

This feels more natural to me and avoids the problem you're experiencing - and is the solution that you came up to on your own.

Comment: I already have this typedef where I define my interfaces. I will still be forced to change the type of _foo which I don't want to do. Instead I'd like _foo to remain as a MockFooPtr, where MockFoo inherits from IFoo.